# Query in SQL GROUP BY period

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I need to make a simple query to count how many record i have in a specific  period of time
like day, month, year, 
 pseudo example:

```
SELECT COUNT( EmployeeID)
FROM  HumanResources.Employees
WHERE   Hire Date.YEAR = 'year'
GROUP BY Hire Date.YEAR
```

this code does not works, what should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query

```
select COUNT(EmployeeID)
from HumanResources.Employees
where year(Hire Date)=2011 
  and month(Hire Date)=03
group by Hire Date
```

If you want to query between date range

```
select COUNT(EmployeeID)
from HumanResources.Employees
where Hire date between '2011/03/01' and '2011/03/03'
group by Hire Date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the YEAR() and MONTH() functions to split information into periods.

For example:

```
SELECT YEAR(Hire Date), MONTH(Hire Date), COUNT( EmployeeID) FROM  
HumanResources.Employees WHERE   YEAR(Hire Date) = 'year' 
GROUP BY YEAR(Hire Date),MONTH(Hire Date)
```

Comment: You are right but remove (.) dot and use space same column name as user type 'Hire Date' instead of 'Hire.Date'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SQL Server DatePart function

```
WHERE DatePart(y, [Hire Date]) = 2011
GROUP BY DatePart(y, [Hire Date])
```

You can substitute y with a number of dateparts (month, quarter, week, day, dayofweek etc)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can establish the start and end dates of the range you want to count the records in then I would use the BETWEEN operator.

```
SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID)
FROM   Employees emp
WHERE  HireDate BETWEEN @rangeStartDate AND @rangeEndDate
```

If working with different ranges is part of what you need, and assuming you are doing this purely in T-SQL, then you could use the DATEADD function to calculate the range end date based on an specific offset and a known range start date.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. to find count of employees hired in 2010:

```
SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) 
FROM HumanResources.Employees 
WHERE [Hire Date] >= '20100101' AND [Hire Date] < '20110101'
```

Doing it this way will mean if there is an index on Hire Date, it will be used (better performance). As soon as you start manipulating the column you are searching on (e.g using YEAR() or MONTH() functions), you lose the ability for an index to be used.

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: Wouldn't the BETWEEN operator acheive the same thing without the need for text base date fields.

Comment: BETWEEN is *inclusive* of the end date, so any records with Hire Date = 20110101 00:00:00 would be included which would be wrong. Also, ideally this would be parameterised anyway with DATETIME variables (didn't show this for conciseness). But in the above, the 2 date strings I've specified would be implicitly converted once to DATETIMEs to then match on the underlying Hide Date field

Comment: ... and these aren't text based date fields. It's the in every localized version working way of type dates within T-SQL. The field [Hire Date] is still a date field - just the static value is given in a text representation.

Comment: I'll confess I've use the text based representation approach on a couple of occasions (once in an application where I was dealing with dates earlier than the minimum data value that SQL Server store in a date field). I just found it confusing to have to remember where you treated a date value as a date or where it needed to treated as a string. Both approaches are valid, I think it boils down to personal taste.

Comment: @OtisAardvark - just to clarify, if a field in a database represents a DATE, I alway used DATETIME type for that column (potentially DATETIME2 now if needed greater scope / accuracy). I'm not treating [Hire Date] as if it's a text-based field

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to convert it to LINQ-to-SQL, following should work:

```
var count = (from e in HumanResourcesDataContext.Employees
             where e.HireDate.Year = 2011 // or whatever you want it to be
             select e).Count();
```